# Crash on importing audio after packaging game EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION OVRlipsync Plugin UE4

Tags: c++, exception, runtime-error, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

Been working on a lipsync project on UE4.27 and the Oculus OVRlipsync and the project has been working very well on UE editor. Packaging the game to ship it to the client, I started facing issues that is related on cooking frame sequence from WAV files resulting in crash in the packaged app.

The resulted crash log is

```
Unhandled Exception: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION reading address 0x0000024bc963002c

OVRLipSync
OVRLipSync
OVRLipSync
OVRLipSync
MyProject_Win64_Shipping!ovrLipSync_ProcessFrameEx() [\software\coretech\src\engines\tracking\facetracking\facewave\ovrlipsyncshim.cpp:389]
MyProject_Win64_Shipping!<lambda_04cfcd2176d25e5a0c33289e1c33f647>::operator()() [D:\Unreal Projects\Lipsync\fix2\MyProject\Plugins\OVRLipSync\Source\OVRLipSync\Private\CreateFrameSequenceAsset.cpp:79]
MyProject_Win64_Shipping!TAsyncRunnable<void>::Run()
MyProject_Win64_Shipping!FRunnableThreadWin::Run()
```

Tracing the error at `CreateFrameSequenceAsset.cpp:79` which was part of the plugin source code I found the following function
`context.ProcessFrame(PCMData + offs, ChunkSizeSamples, Visemes, LaughterScore, FrameDelayInMs,NumChannels > 1);`

putting efforts back on the declaration and definition of the function found nothing useful, except that I tried looking up the file `ovrlipsyncshim.cpp` and found nothing so I tried searching my project for `ProcessFrameEx()` I found another part of it in `/ThirdParty/Include/OVRLipSync.h` as follows

```
ovrLipSyncResult ovrLipSync_ProcessFrameEx(
    ovrLipSyncContext context,
    const void* audioBuffer,
    int sampleCount,
    ovrLipSyncAudioDataType dataType,
    ovrLipSyncFrame* pFrame);
```

though tracing all this up couldn't find anything useful to handle the exception or tell the cause of it.

Anyone ever faced such a problem or having any experience solving such an issue

Comment: Just because this is where the program crashes or reports an error doesn't mean this is where the problem is. C++ does not work this way. The problem can be anywhere in your code, but after the bug occurs the program keeps running for a little bit before it finally crashes here. This is why stackoverflow.com's [help] requires you to show a [mre] that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, then compile, run, and reproduce your problem. See [ask] for more information. Until you do that, it is unlikely that anyone will be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I've changed a line in **OvrLipSyncEditorModule.cpp**:

**From**:

```
UOVRLipSyncContextWrapper context(ovrLipSyncContextProvider_Enhanced, SampleRate, 4096, ModelPath);
```

**To**:

```
UOVRLipSyncContextWrapper context(ovrLipSyncContextProvider_Enhanced, SampleRate, 8192, ModelPath);
```

(basically I've increased the buffer size)

And I've also added this line:

```
SoundWave->LoadingBehavior = ESoundWaveLoadingBehavior::ForceInline;
```

**before the call**:

```
DecompressSoundWave(SoundWave);
```

Now it doesn't crash anymore and it generates a sequence, but when I attach the sequence to the model, it does nothing.. It's weird, it seems to not be a working sequence even though I've checked and the sequence is not empty.